# How to fail Azure devops pipeline task specifically for failures in build-steps.yaml file - bash

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3MHE.jpg)
although terraform validate has an error the build didn't stop , and here is the part in build-steps.yaml:

```yaml
 - task: TerraformCLI@0
    displayName: "Run Terraform fmt"
    inputs:
      command: 'fmt'
      commandOptions: '-check -recursive'
      allowTelemetryCollection: false

  - bash: |
     find . -type f \
       -name "*.tf" | \
       xargs -I % dirname % | \
       sort -u | \
       xargs -I ? bash -c \
         '(cd ? && terraform init -backend=false && terraform validate ; rm -rf .terraform)' \ 

    displayName: "Run Terraform validate"
```

I've tried `continueOnError: false`, but it didn't work.

```yaml
- task: TerraformCLI@0
    displayName: "Run Terraform fmt"
    inputs:
      command: 'fmt'
      commandOptions: '-check -recursive'
      allowTelemetryCollection: false

 - bash: |
    find . -type f \
      -name "*.tf" | \
      xargs -I % dirname % | \
      sort -u | \
      xargs -I ? bash -c \
        '(cd ? && terraform init -backend=false && terraform validate ; rm -rf .terraform)' \ 

   displayName: "Run Terraform validate" 
   continueOnError: false
```

Comment: could you please explain why are you using a bash task when you can use Task: TerraformCLI again to init, validate, and other things 
Additionally, why don't you just switch to the directory where .tf files are available run terraform init, validate etc?

Comment: actually it's a template we are all using it in the company , can i stop the build while using the bash or must i use task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can use the `TerraformCLl` task to run terraform validate.

```
- task: TerraformCLI@0
   displayName: "Run Terraform fmt"
   inputs:
     command: 'validate'
     commandOptions: 'xxxx'
     allowTelemetryCollection: false
```

> Can I stop the build while using the bash?

You can try to enable the option "`Fail on Standard Error`" for the bash task. If this is true, this task will fail if any errors are written to the `StandardError` stream.

For example:

```
 - bash: |
    find . -type f \
      -name "*.tf" | \
      xargs -I % dirname % | \
      sort -u | \
      xargs -I ? bash -c \
        '(cd ? && terraform init -backend=false && terraform validate ; rm -rf .terraform)' \ 

   displayName: "Run Terraform validate" 
   failOnStderr: true
```

Alternately, use `set -e` inside the script:

```
 - bash: |
    set -e
    find . -type f \
      -name "*.tf" | \
      xargs -I % dirname % | \
      sort -u | \
      xargs -I ? bash -c \
        '(cd ? && terraform init -backend=false && terraform validate ; rm -rf .terraform)' \ 

   displayName: "Run Terraform validate"
```